# Returning a protocol with associatedtype from another protocol API

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a `Session` protocol with an `Output` associated type:

```
public protocol SessionAPI {
  associatedtype Output: Equatable
  var output: Output { get }
}
```

And a concrete implementation of the protocol that returns a `String`:

```
public final class StringSession: SessionAPI {
  public typealias Output = String
  public let output: String
}
```

Let's assume that the implementation of `StringSession` is very complex and touches many modules, and I don't want to add dependencies to those modules in classes that use the SessionAPI.  So I have another protocol that vends StringSessions using a generic factory method:

```
public protocol SessionFactoryAPI {
  func createStringFactory<T: SessionAPI>() -> T where T.Output == String
}
```

All of this compiles fine.  However, when I try to implement the factory API, I get a compilation error:

> public final class SessionFactory: SessionFactoryAPI {
> public func createStringFactory<T: SessionAPI>() -> T where T.Output == String {
> // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'StringSession' to expected argument type 'T'
> return StringSession()
> }
> }

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Can you provide details of how you are implementing the factory API, please?

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Cannot convert value of type 'StringSession' to expected argument type 'T' return

Means that the compiler doesn't know that `T` should be `SessionAPI`.

In `SessionFactoryAPI`:

```swift
public protocol SessionFactoryAPI {
  func createStringFactory<T: SessionAPI>() -> T where T.Output == String
}
```

you are only specifying what `T.Output` should be (ie. `String`)

If you really need the constraint `Output == String`, you can try declaring a `StringSessionAPI` protocol:

```swift
public protocol StringSessionAPI: SessionAPI where Output == String { }
public final class StringSession: StringSessionAPI {
    public typealias Output = String

    public let output: String
    public init(output: String) {
        self.output = output
    }
}
```

and return `any StringSessionAPI`

```
public protocol SessionFactoryAPI {
    func createStringFactory() -> any StringSessionAPI
}

struct MyFactory: SessionFactoryAPI {
    func createStringFactory() -> any StringSessionAPI {
        StringSession(output: "output")
    }
}

let factory = MyFactory()
let stringSession: any StringSessionAPI = factory.createStringFactory()
print(stringSession.output) // prints "output"
```

Or you can try using by using an associated type, instead of a generic function:

```swift
public protocol SessionFactoryAPI {
    associatedtype T: SessionAPI where T.Output == String
    func createStringFactory() -> T
}

struct MyFactory: SessionFactoryAPI {
    func createStringFactory() -> StringSession {
        .init(output: "output")
    }
}

let factory = MyFactory()
let stringSession: StringSession = factory.createStringFactory()
print(stringSession.output) // prints "output"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!  I feel like the "any" keyword always kinda slips my mind...I haven't fully internalized when I need to be using it.

Comment: check out this [article](https://www.donnywals.com/what-is-the-any-keyword-in-swift/)